# Extract information from a webpage

Tags: python, selenium

Please could you help me how to get the mobile model and it its price from the following  using python.
I wanted to extract the name Moto E(Black) and Rs.6999 from the page. I tried the same using selenium in Python(I am a beginner to selenium). Here is my code. Please help me out.

```
from selenium import webdriver 
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys

driver = webdriver.Firefox()
driver.get("http://www.kart123.com/mobiles/pr?p%5B%5D=sort%3Dfeatured&sid=tyy%2C4io&ref=68c7d088-ae7f-4310-aa4c-a7ee176d168d")
elem=driver.find_element_by_xpath("//div[@class='product-unit unit-4 
browse-product']")
elem1=elem.find_element_by_xpath("//div[@class='pu-details lastUni']")
elem2=elem1.find_element_by_xpath("//div[@class='pu-title
fk-font-13']") print
elem2.find_element_by_xpath(".//a[@class='fk-display-block']").text<br>
driver.close()

<div class=' product-unit unit-4  browse-product  ' data-pid="MOBDVHC6XKKPZ3GZ" data-tracking-products=";MOBDVHC6XKKPZ3GZ;1;6999;;eVar22=Mobile" data-size="store-grid-new-4">
    <div class='pu-visual-section'>
        <a data-tracking-id="prd_img"  class='pu-image fk-product-thumb ' href="/moto-e/p/itmdvuwsybgnbtha?pid=MOBDVHC6XKKPZ3GZ&srno=b_1&ref=83c37824-b74d-4121-8be0-27731ddccde2">
        <img alt="Moto E: Mobile" data-error-url="http://img1a.flixcart.com/mob/thumb/mobile.jpg" onload="img_onload(this);" onerror="img_onerror(this);" src="http://img5a.flixcart.com/image/mobile/3/g/z/motorola-xt1022-125x125-imadvvfknshcywk5.jpeg"></img>
        </a>
    </div>
    <div class="pu-details lastUnit">
        <div class="pu-title fk-font-13">
            <a class="fk-display-block" data-tracking-id="prd_title" href="/moto-e/p/itmdvuwsybgnbtha?pid=MOBDVHC6XKKPZ3GZ&srno=b_1&ref=83c37824-b74d-4121-8be0-27731ddccde2" title="*Moto E (Black)*">
            Moto E (Black)
            </a>
        </div>
        <div class='pu-variants  fk-font-11'>
            and <a href="/moto-e/p/itmdvuwsybgnbtha?pid=MOBDVHC6XKKPZ3GZ&srno=b_1&ref=83c37824-b74d-4121-8be0-27731ddccde2">1 more variant</a>
        </div>
        <div class="pu-extra fk-font-11">
        </div>
        <div class="pu-rating" data-ratingfor="ITMDVUWSYBGNBTHA#MOBDVHC6XKKPZ3GZ#moto-e">
            <div class='fk-stars-small' title ='4.7 stars'>
                <div class='rating' style='width:94%;'>
                </div>
            </div>
            (852 ratings)<span class="ugc-summary-icon"></span>
        </div>
        <div class="pu-price">
            <div class="pu-border-top">
                <div class="pu-final">
                    <span class="fk-font-17 fk-bold">**Rs. 6999**</span>
                </div>
                <div class="pu-emi fk-font-12">EMI from Rs. 626</div>
                <div class="pu-personal">
                </div>
                <ul class="pu-offers">
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="pu-border-top">
            <ul class="pu-usp">
                <li><span class="text">Android v4.4 OS</span></li>
                <li><span class="text">4.3-inch Touchscreen</span></li>
                <li><span class="text">1 GB RAM</span></li>
                <li><span class="text">Dual SIM (GSM + GSM)</span></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
        <div class="pu-compare pu-border-top">
            <input type="checkbox" class="compare-checkbox" data-uniqid="83c37824-b74d-4121-8be0-27731ddccde2" id="MOBDVHC6XKKPZ3GZ" display_vertical='Mobiles' vertical="mobile"  vertical_url_map='/mobiles'><label for="MOBDVHC6XKKPZ3GZ" class="compare-label">Add to compare</label>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
</div>
<div class="gd-col gu3">
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! It looks like you want us to write some code for you. While many users are willing to produce code for a coder in distress, they usually only help when the poster has already tried to solve the problem on their own. A good way to demonstrate this effort is to include the code you've written so far, example input (if there is any), the expected output, and the output you actually get (console output, stack traces, compiler errors - whatever is applicable). The more detail you provide, the more answers you are likely to receive.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a few tools out there for what you're trying to do.

**Scrapy** (http://doc.scrapy.org) is a great tool for writing web crawlers and keeping you data up to date. You can use XPath notation to access data (for instance `div[@class='pu-final']/
span/text()` would give you Rs. 6999).

If you don't all Scrapy's features and don't really need performance (like a one-time import script), there is also **BeautifulSoup** (http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/) which is really simple to use.

Those are just two of the many tools you could use, but they're pretty well documented. I'm sure many people here could recommend you some other great tools, make your choice according to what fits your needs best.

Good luck.